# Why is some of the text I extracted not properly decoded in Python?

Tags: python, edgar

I have written the following code to download the text of a financial report of Apple on the SEC:

```
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'email'}
response = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312514383437/0001193125-14-383437.txt', headers=headers)
content = response.content.decode()
try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    if soup is None:
        raise Exception("Failed to parse with html.parser")
except Exception as e:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
text = soup.get_text()
print(text)
```

This returns the full decoded text file of the financial report I have downloaded. However, some of the output is not properly decoded. So for example, instead of `Company's` the output shows `Company’s`. I have tried encoding and decoding again, but that does not work, so now I am pretty much stuck. I hope someone knows how I should modify my code to get the desired output.

Comment: show us an example that doesnt work as you expect... eg `soup=BeautifulSoup('<div>company's</div>','lxml')` should work fine ...

Comment: `decode()` is for decoding binary character encoding schemes, it doesn't translate between different characters. It won't turn apostrophe to single quote.

Comment: @JoranBeasley He did, although it wasn't easy to see in his question formatting.

Comment: FYI, I found the linked question by googling "python convert apostrophe to ascii"

Comment: @Barmar the linked question is literally not answered. The answer just removes the character completely. That is not what I want, but I am sorry you thought I did no research at all. And just a suggestion to you, you should try to use some kindness. Also, the output does not show Company’s but just an error.

Comment: @larzz_010 The answer using the Unidecode library seems to do exactly what you want. `Gavin O’Connor` => `Gavin O'Connor`